# Copying formulae while using name range

Tags: excel

I am using index match function and has given named range as cell reference. However if I try to paste it for other column, it remains static and reference does not change.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards,
Abhinav

Comment: Named range will act as absolute reference and it won't change relatively. If you wanted to change the reference of the name, you need to edit the range associated with the name. but that would affect all other places where you used named range.

Answer (score 1):

By default Named Ranges are absolute. You can create relative Name Ranges using Name manager but it can be hard to work out what to enter as the range, and it appears to keep changing depending on what the active cell is

If you want to create relative named ranges I recommend switching to R1C1 mode:

If you define RelName as =R[-1]C[-2] for instance it means one row above and 2 column to the left of whatever formula you add the Name to, and it will still mean one row above and 2 cols to the left from wherever you paste it to.